# How do you find the derivative of $2^{\sin(\pi x)}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I don't understand how to take the derivative of this expression.
$$y=2^{\sin (\pi x)}$$

Answer (score 5):

The function is $e^{(\ln 2)(\sin(\pi x))}$. Now use the Chain Rule.

**Remark:** Essentially the same idea will deal with the derivative of $(f(x))^{g(x)}$, where $f(x)$ is a positive function. Use the fact that
$$(f(x))^{g(x)}=e^{(\ln(f(x))(g(x))},$$
and use the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to apply the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=2^{\sin(\pi x)}$ and let $g(x)=\ln(f(x))$. Then $g(x)=\ln(2)\cdot\sin(\pi x)$ so
$$
g^\prime(x)=\ln(2)\pi\cdot\cos(\pi x)\tag{1}
$$
But we also have
$$
g^\prime(x)=\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}
$$
which gives
$$
f^\prime(x)=f(x)\cdot g^\prime(x)\tag{2}
$$
Putting (1) and (2) together gives
$$
f^\prime(x)=2^{\sin(\pi x)}\cdot \ln(2)\pi\cdot\cos(\pi x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the equation be $$a^{u(x)}=e^{u(x)\log(a)}$$ So the derivative is $$\Big(u(x)\log(a)\Big)'e^{u(x)\log(a)}=\log(a)~u'(x)~e^{u(x)\log(a)}=\log(a)~u'(x)~a^{u(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing you have to use here is the [Chain Rule](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/taking-derivatives/chain_rule/v/derivatives-of-sin-x-cos-x-tan-x-e-x-and-ln-x) which states that:
$$(f(g(x)))' = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

---

$$ y = 2^{\sin (\pi x)}
 \implies \log_2y = \sin (\pi x)\\
\implies \frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(2)}=\sin(\pi x)\\
 \implies \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \ln(2)\cdot\cos(\pi x)\cdot \pi \\
\implies \frac{dy}{dx} =  \pi\ln(2)\cdot 2^{sin (\pi x)}\cdot\cos (\pi x)$$

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to convert the expresssion to a power of $e$.
$$e^{\ln 2}=e^{\ln 2}$$
$$\text{so }2=e^{\ln 2}$$
Then
$$2^{\sin (\pi x)}=\bigg(e^{\ln 2}\bigg) ^{\sin(\pi x)}=e^{\ln 2\cdot\sin(\pi x)}$$
Now just apply the chain rule.
$$\frac{de^{\ln 2\cdot\sin(\pi x)}}{d \ln 2\cdot\sin(\pi x)}\cdot\frac{d \ln 2\cdot\sin(\pi x)}{d\sin(\pi x)}\cdot\frac{d\sin(\pi x)}{d\pi x}\cdot\frac{d\pi x}{dx}$$

If you prefer, another way of writing this out is with multiple variables.
given$\dots$
$$w=\pi x$$
$$v=\sin w$$
$$u=(\ln2)\cdot v$$
the derivative expression becomes
$$\frac{de^{u}}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dv}\cdot\frac{dv}{dw}\cdot\frac{dw}{dx}$$